# Convert number date into a string date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to convert number date to string date like? (refer below)

```
2015-07-03 = July 03, 2015 where July is 07 (month), 03 (day), 2015 (year)
```

Any help, suggestions, ideas, clues, recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @HayleyGuillou: Don't use w3schools. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead.

Comment: you seem to have the date as a string in US short form (not sure about that last one), and want it as a string in some custom format. what you need to do is "parse date string with javascript" (which will probably give you a time-stamp, which is a single number) followed by "format date with javascript". use web-search for these two.

Comment: its a custom date (e.g 2015-07-03) given from a back end, what I really want is convert that from 2015-07-03 to July 03, 2015

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function called `toDateString()` which will convert date to string.

Here is the sample link :

http://jsfiddle.net/naveenravi/wow1tmbg/

Comment: its a custom date (e.g 2015-07-03) given from a back end, what I really want is convert that from 2015-07-03 to July 03, 2015

Comment: you can pass your date in that function like i did in the below link :http://jsfiddle.net/naveenravi/wow1tmbg/1/

Answer (score 0):

To extract the date in this format you can use the code

```
var objDate = new Date("2015-07-03"),
    locale = "en-us",
    month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long"});
    year = objDate.getFullYear();
    day = objDate.getDate();
console.log(month+',' + day + " " + year);
```